# Javascript onkeydown code to clear text value from search box not working in mozilla firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox

I'm trying to make search box where after typing anything inside search box, press ESC key & It will clear text. everything is working fine in Google Chrome & Safari, but Javascript Code not working in Mozilla Firefox browser & I'm not able to fix it.

```js
document.onkeydown = function (evtesc) {
 "use strict";
 evtesc = evtesc || window.event;

 if (evtesc.keyCode === 27) {
  document.getElementById("search-largeinput").value = "";
 }
};
```

```html
<form>
<input id="search-largeinput" type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search SiteName.com">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `document.onkeyup`:

```js
document.onkeydown = function (evtesc) {
  if (evtesc.keyCode === 27) {
    document.getElementById("search-largeinput").value = "";
  }
};
```

Or use `document.addEventListener`:

```js
document.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
  if (evtesc.keyCode === 27) {
    document.getElementById("search-largeinput").value = "";
  }
};
```

The [`keydown`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/keydown) event is fired before the default behavior for the keyboard event updated the input's value. So you change the value manually and after that, the browser updates the value itself.